# How to clear dropdownlist contorl in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help how to clear dropdownlist control in Javascript

Answer (score 8):

```
document.getElementById('idofselectbox').options.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove its child elements which are `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function RemoveItems()
{
   var objDrpList = document.getElementById ('theIdOfYourDdl');

   for(i=objDrpList.length-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
      if(objDrpList.options[i].selected)
      {
         objDrpList.options[i] = null;
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Darin's answer is actually the way to go. Both work, but less code is better.